# Running a macro a dynamic # of times

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, listboxitem

I have a user form where users can enter values in a text field which get put into a list box, which will always be a dynamic number of entries. When they select "Done" how do I get VBA to recognize each line separately?

They are entering property names and I have a code that says copy template x number of times and rename each as the value which has been entered.

I was trying to say:

```
Dim cellNumber As Integer
Dim property As ListBox.Items

cellNumber = 11 
For Each property In ListBox1
   Range("B" & cellNumber).Value = property

   'copying template and renaming it
   Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets("Template")
   ActiveSheet.Name = property
```

Comment: are the 'entries' just the user hitting return? i.e. it is a list delimited by a newline?

Comment: So, is it one textbox, and the user enters some amount of like commma separated entries? like prop1,prop2,prop3,prop4 etc... or is it a number of textboxes and each textbox may or may not have a value in it?

Comment: oh the listbox will have an unknown amount of entries in it, and you want the code to loop through each item in it?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 Dim cellNumber As Integer
 Dim property As string


cellNumber = 11 
For i = 0 to listbox1.listcount - 1    '-1 because the .list starts at 0
    property = listbox1.list(i)
    Range("B" & cellNumber).Value = property

'copying template and renaming it
    Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets("Template")
    ActiveSheet.Name = property
next
```

that will process all entries in that list box.

if you're wondering how to populate it:

if you have 1 textbox where the user enters multiple comma delimited properties, like prop1,prop2,prop3, etc.. then you'd use

```
dim values as variant
values = split(txtbox.text, ",") ' where you can use any delimiter
```

then you'd do:

```
dim val as string
for each val in values
    listbox1.add(val)
next
```

if you have multiple textboxes you simply loop through the controls on the form checking the typename and adding the values if they are not empty. like:

```
dim ctrl as control
for each ctrl in form.controls
    if typename ctrl = "Textbox" then
        if not ctrl.text= "" then 
            listbox1.add(ctrl.text)
        end if
    end if
next
```